# Show div after 5 next clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have 2 divs on a container.I would like to get first image from div with id="underscore" 4 times from 5.I have 5 images which changes and for first 4 i would like to have the image from first div only.On the last image,i must hide the 1st div image and show the 2nd div image.

I have tryed:

```
$(document).ready( function() { 
    $('#underscore').show();
    $('#underscore_umbrela').hide();

    if(imgNumber < 4){
        $('#underscore').hide();
    $('#underscore_umbrela').show();
    }
        } 

<div id="underscore" class="underscore">
       <div><img id="underscore" src="images/underscore.png" alt=""/></div>
       <div><img id="underscore_umbrela" src="images/underscore_umbrela.png" alt=""/></div>
       </div>
```

Comment: where was declared your 'imgNumber' ?

Comment: On which event do u want this requirement to be happen??

Comment: Why the down vote?  It's a legitimate question.

Comment: I have made a fiddle with all code in it : http://jsfiddle.net/ygaw2/41/ here we go :)

Comment: That doesn't help at all.  I've answered the question you asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya can't have the same ID shared between two or more elements, so I've updated your markup

```
<div id="wrapper" class="underscore">
    <div><img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200" id="underscore" /></div>
    <div><img src="http://placekitten.com/400/400" id="underscore_umbrella" /></div>
</div>
```

Here's the javascript to achieve the fifth-click show:

```
$(function() {
    var counter = 0,
        $img1 = $('#underscore'),
        $img2 = $('#underscore_umbrella');

    $img1.show(); // Set img1 as visible (if it isn't already)
    $img2.hide(); // Set img2 as hidden

    $('#wrapper').on('click', function() {
        if (counter === 4) {
            $img1.hide();
            $img2.show();
            counter = 0;
        } else {
            $img1.show();
            $img2.hide();
            counter += 1;
        }
    });
});
```

And here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dDrt5/)

Comment: Your code looks awesome,i have implemented something,heres a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/ygaw2/42/ ...the problem on my code is that the page start with underscore_umbrela not with underscore...after 1 next its oke,it start with undescore img then after 4 next clicks it shows undercore_umbrela img which is good...But why it start with undescore_umbrela if i set it hide :(

Comment: I figurate out...it works oke from first click (i mean hiding underscore_umbrela and showing underscore coz all it was in a function which is called by click ...) so i made another function with  $('#underscore_umbrela').hide(); which is called when document load :) now when document load shows underscore untill 5th image which is changed into underscore_umbrela :x

Comment: can i @monners made a function or something to clear my drop content when the answer is wrong? I have made a submit function which tells with alerts if is wrong or right...on both situations the dropped area has content on it but i only want to keep it when the answer is right...u can check the fiddle to see what i mean

Comment: I figurate out again :D